# How to login to wordpress website before setting webView in android

Tags: android, authentication, http-authentication

I have a wordpress site. I want to cast a webView onto a page which requires authentication. How can I set the user logged in?

Please help me

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    WebView wvCourse = (WebView) mainview.findViewById(R.id.wvCourse);
    wvCourse.loadUrl(url);
    WebSettings settings = wvCourse.getSettings();
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wvCourse.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvCourse.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    return mainview;
}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public void TestFunction() {
        Log.e("username", pref.getString("username_val", ""));
        Log.e("here","here");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                                      HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        TestFunction();
        handler.proceed("user123","user_123");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code please

Comment: @HadjKhelilNawrez please check the edit.